# Text size in dp

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, textview

So I'm totally lost now I have problems with Text size ruing my UI when user sets his font size through **Accessibility -> Font size** to **Huge** so for quick fix I decided to change all text sizes to **dp** instead of **sp** that text would always be same size but on some places **textviews** even when **textsize** is set to **dp** resizes any idea why??

Here is button with text size set to **dp** which maintains font size even after changing through accessibility

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/video_button"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/webshop_button"
        android:text="@string/button_3dvideo_text"/>
```

And here is **textView** which ignores **textSize** even after setting it to **dp**:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/color_white"
        android:text="@string/about"/>
```

Comment: If you at nougat user can able to change their fontsize in settings so once its done out UI screen will be smaller or bigger . so we need to design responsively to adopt any screen dimension.

Comment: good point, but for now I need quick fix because my UI is not accessible to users who sets their font size through settings

Comment: Even you'll try to use dp it will change that is the android design for adapting any dimension screen for perfect fit.  https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html  The size for Textview changes as per the device specification we can't put a control over there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have a solution for this which will make the font size non changeable in your app :

```
 public void adjustFontScale(Configuration configuration) {
    configuration.fontScale = (float) 1;
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    metrics.scaledDensity = configuration.fontScale * metrics.density;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, metrics);
}
```

Call this method in onCreate of your every Activity or you can make a Base Activity:

```
 adjustFontScale(getResources().getConfiguration());
```

You can change the fontScale according to your needs.
Hope this helps.

Comment: works great, just that I had to put it in all fragments as well before inflating view otherwise it doesn't work properly

Comment: What i do is implement in a baseclass i will post that too

Answer (score 2):

May be try to use this Not sure whether its going to help you.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float dp = 20f;
    float fpixels = metrics.density * dp;
    int pixels = (int) (fpixels + 0.5f);
    Edit_click.setTextSize(pixels);
```

Comment: code works, it sets textSize, but still text is resized whenever you change it through accessibility

Comment: Already said we don't have a  control over it may be the another answer help you.